# Can I passively do anything to fix an anterior pelvic tilt?

Tags: stretching, health, back-pain, lower-back, back

I'm not sure I worded the question right, hope I can explain myself better here. If someone can help, please edit the title and remove this.

I suffer from APT and have been trying to fix it for months. I've seen a lot of improvement from foam rolling, static stretching and simply trying to keep a good posture at all times. However, since I started a new job I've been sitting 8+ hours everyday and don't have as much time as I used to to perform the stretches, which all together has deteriorated the condition again.

I'm not asking for stretches or exercises that will help fix the APT, as I know those already. Is there anything **that would not be considered an exercise** that I can easily do either at the office or at home and will help fix my APT? I'm talking about things such as sitting cross legged or with wide open legs (probably one is better than the other, although I don't know which) or sleeping in a certain position.

Comment: If you have room in your office, I strongly suggest you to do some small sessions every 3 hours or so. If someone asks just let them know your condition(amount of detail is up to you) My coworker with whom I share my office with has a sciatica, so she needs to do stretches too every now and then, she even keeps a yoga mat in here.

Comment: @JustDoIt I already do that. Standing up and walking up and down the stairs frequently, and doing some quad and hip stretches every couple of hours or so. It's just not enough for me, so that's why I'm wondering if there's anything I can do "passively" to help.

Comment: You can check out the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l2VQ_WZ8Bto . Basically you strap a rubber band through your shoulders and around your back (kind like you would wear a body holster for two handguns) and wear it for a while. While this is not APT specific, it is supposed to give you a better overall posture: chest forward and up and shoulders out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are doing everything that can be done to help your condition. The best I can do is to give you ideas for inspiration.

**1)** [Get the right chair.](http://www.anteriorpelvictilthq.com/benefits-ergonomic-chair/) Since you are sitting down all the time, there might be some special chairs that can help sit in a better position.

**2)** [Change setting position every so often.](https://michalzuber.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/sitting-positions.png) Maybe once every 30 to 60 minutes

**3)** Lay down while working if possible.

**4)** Work while standing. Get a table with adjustable height.

**5)** Try heat. [This page](http://www.anteriorpelvictilthq.com/10-products-to-help-with-your-anterior-pelvic-tilt/) suggests that as well as some other products to fight pelvic tilt.

**6)** [Consider getting a shiatsu seat for your chair.](http://www.zyllioninc.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/cd856005ddd771aead6c4187d4aaf078/z/m/zma-14-bk.jpg) They also come with heated seats.

I know you already know exercises, [but consider some of the hip mobility exercises as described here.](http://antranik.org/the-floreio-project/)

You might also [know this page](http://www.swolept.com/posts/fixing-anterior-pelvic-tilt-posture-tricks-to-make-your-butt-and-gut-smaller), but if you don't, it might be helpful.

I would love to hear your results in the comments if you try some of them.

**UPDATE**

Oh yes, I can also warmly recommend [this special thoracic bridge stretch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rm9L0RIhR3s). It work wonders in loosening up your shoulder blades and thoracic spine (spine between your shoulder blades). Working on your spine might improve alignment in your hips. Who knows? Maybe your hip tilt is the result of compensating for an inflexible spine.

Regardless, that stretch will do wonders for your upper back and prevent rounded shoulders :)